# how do I assign specific json data for web automation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm using puppeteer to do web automations. I'm automating the task to fill up a form. My script is set to open multiple browsers so as to automate filling the form alot faster. However I need each browser automation to use separate information. Here's the code below.

```
for(let i = 0; i<json.length; i++){
  await page.type('#firstName', json[i].firstName);
  await page.type('#lastName', json[i].lastName);
  await page.type('#phone', json[i].phone);
  await page.type('#address1', json[i].unitNumber);
  await page.type('#address2', json[i].address1);
  await page.type('#address3', json[i].address2); //not complusory(for sg region ONLY)
  await page.type('#town', json[i].townCity);
  await page.type('#county', json[i].stateProvince); //not complusory(for sg region ONLY)
  await page.type('#postcodeLook', json[i].postalCode);
}
```

Here's my json (just a template but there would be lines of information in this format.)

```
firstName;lastName;phone;unitNumber;address1;address2;townCity;stateProvince;postalCode
```

There error Im facing is that when inputing the data into the form it actually fills in the whole list of information into one of the forms input section. What I mean is , e.g for firstName it will fill in firstName1, firstName2, firstName3 and so on depending on the number of data in the json. How would I fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you remove the `for loop` I'm pretty sure you're issue will go away. If it does, then you aren't using multiple browsers in the way you think you are.

Comment: @hor53 I've actually tried removing the `for loop` but it would say `i is not defined`

Comment: Of course it will. You need to operate on a single element of your `json` object (by the way, bad name for a variable). First assign the value to an object such as `let jsonData = json[0]`, then change all references to `json[i]` to `jsonData`. If you are trying to use each element of your `json` array in a different browser, then for each browser let `jsonData` be a unique element.

Comment: oh alright thanks! I think I got it. Sorry bout the naming bad habits. :(

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you are working through the issue. For more details, the reason I say `json` is a bad name for a variable is `JSON` (uppercase) is a common JavaScript module and mixing the two can be confusing. Also, `json` doesn't tell the reader much about what the object is. Is it raw json text? An instance of a JSON object? A utility to interact with json? You get the idea :)

Comment: @h0r53 I'm actually gonna base the number of browsers automation on user input. So I cant assign fixed values to the `jsonData`, would there be a way to assign e.g `(i=0 ; i<BrowserNumber ; i++)` but without it being in a loop?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example and I would be happy to take a look

Comment: @meliz please share the page you're automating and a [mcve] of your code and JSON, preferably runnable, so we can help. Please explain what behavior you want -- are you trying to open, fill and submit the page with the form on it `n` times, for each entry in your JSON? If so, you probably want to move your loop around whatever code generates the `page` and performs navigation to your target resource so that each form submission uses `json[i]`. Thanks.